# c++ UDP socket programming in ubuntu

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I'm trying to learn udp socket programming in c++ but I can't find a useful tutorial and a useful example code . can anybody help me to find some?

Comment: There are quite literally tens of *thousands* of socket tutorials and examples on the Internet! I doubt you can't find a single one that couldn't help you.

Comment: this will be off-topic ... suggest you read about how to ask questions.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't find any guides, but to be kind - one might consider checking out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this is what you should follow either if you're on Windows or Linux:

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/c-c-sockets-faq-and-how-to-win-linux.56901/